# Mapping covariant interface

Tags: entity-framework

Can I map the following domain model using Entity Framework Code First?

```
public abstract class ContentBase { ... }

public class ContentA : ContentBase { ... }

public class ContentB : ContentBase { ... }

public interface IContainer<out TContent>
    where TContent : ContentBase { ... }

public abstract class ContainerBase<TContent> : IContainer<TContent>
    where TContent : ContentBase
{
    public IList<TContent> Items { get; }
}

public class ContainerA : ContainerBase<ContentA> { ... }

public class ContainerB : ContainerBase<ContentB> { ... }

public class Apple
{
    public IList<IContainer<ContentBase>> Stuff { get; }
}

public class Orange
{
    public IContainer<ContentBase> Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

I've already implemented my domain model, but I haven't starting mapping it to the database yet.  Today I read that Entity Framework cannot map properties typed as interfaces, so I am concerned that I will run into trouble when I do the mapping.

Comment: You can map concrete classes only, but those classes can implement interfaces. It's just that EF doesn't do anything with the interface. The generic type is a bigger problem. You won't be able to map it.

Comment: @GertArnold Can I at least indirectly map a generic type via a non-generic class that inherits from it?  In the example, can I map `ContainerA` and `ContainerB`?

Comment: I think you can, yes, but why don't you just try?